# jquerymobile how to hide search bar of listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 3 listViews, 2 of them have data-filter="true" and I perform a filter programatically when the user clicks on the previous listview such as a categori filter.

What is the current way to hide the filter bar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try `$(selector).removeAttr("data-filter")` and then refresh the listview. Otherwise you could toggle the `display` via CSS.

When you say hide, do you mean disable or just make it not visible to that list?

**Edit:**

Quick Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YF3nN/

The filter is added as so via JQM:

```
<form class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-c" role="search">
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-c">
        <input class="ui-input-text ui-body-c" placeholder="Filter items..." data-type="search">
        <a class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
    </div>
</form>
```

So all you have to do is select the correct `form` and you can hide it.

Comment: Here's a better selector for the example I provided: `$("#list1").prev("form.ui-listview-filter").toggle();` That way you can hide a specific filter versus all of them.

Comment: Very tks for your help. I'm trying it now

Comment: Welcome, I updated my example again with two lists so you can see how each is selected and each filter can be hidden.